# identify XHR (ajax) response while listening to http response in firefox addon

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a simple firefox addon (addon-sdk) which listens to http resposes and blocks if content type of response matches a set of content types. Now, the observer listens to all the responses when I am not interested in listening to image, javascript files and ajax (XHR) responses. Can I somehow filter out or atleast find out that response belongs to an XHR request so that I don't waste resources on processing the response.

The similar thing can be achieved in chrome extensions where "details.type" can be main_frame, image, xhr etc.

```
httpResponseObserver =  
{  
  observe: function(subject, topic, data)  
  {  

    if (topic == "http-on-examine-response") 
    {
        var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel); 
        var contentType;
        try {
                contentType = channel.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                if (/\b(?:xml|rss|javascript|vnd|json|html|text|image|ocsp|x-shockwave-flash)\b/.test(contentType))
                {
                    return;
                } 
            } 
        catch(error) {
                return;
            }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request the `nsIXMLHttpRequest` interface from `notificationCallbacks`

```js
var isXHR;

try{
  var channel = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
  var callbacks = channel.notificationCallbacks;
  var xhr = callbacks ? callbacks.getInterface(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest) : null;
  isXHR = !!xhr;
}
catch(e){
  isXHR = false;
}
```

Comment: Superb!! Can we do this with images too? Can we diffrentiate between frame and non-frame loads with Ci? What all can we do this with? I was using the flags which was a confusing solution to me.

Comment: Im guesising the try catch is because callbacks may be null? is this true? so if null then theres no getInterace?

Comment: Image detection can be done through the MIME type. The try catch is required by the `getInterface` which will throw if the requested interface is not found. I'm not sure about the frame/non-frame issue, wouldn't they return a different DOM window?

Comment: Can you please give example I have never done mime type stuff +1 though for the pointer

Comment: Check `channel.contentType`

Comment: Thanks man I can't get over just how cool this method is to check if it's ajax!

Comment: @paa Thanks. Even I was looking for `channel.contentType` this helped.

Answer (score 1):

`channel.cancel(Components.results.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);`

so put this before your return line in that if :)

to detect what kind of request ie image ajax u have to check flags:
see the code here do ctrl+f for disposition and look at those flags

for ajax/xhr  some testing i did awhile ago this was the combination of flags to identify it:

```
LOAD_REQUESTMASK |
LOAD_BACKGROUND |
INHIBIT_PIPELINE |
LOAD_EXPLICIT_CREDENTIALS |
DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT
//so tested on w3schools, if flags come out to be this above, then it is an ajax request, can have INHIBIT_CACHING flag
```

plz share any findings you have im interested as im learning too

Comment: it is only a part of the code, i have already done that, I just want to identify xhr responses

Comment: Ah I see you filter this out based on flags. Im not sure about ajax but you have to find some combination when you do please let me know Im interested. You can detect images etc easy with flags. Ill edit solution above