# Prevent JavaScript redirects in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, noscript

I want to prevent JavaScript redirects in Firefox for one domain (youtube.com), and I was wondering whether there's a plugin that will do it.  I'm trying to use NoScript, and I'd like to allow scripts globally because I don't want to disable most JavaScript, but this seems to just allow JavaScript redirects.  Is there a way for me to just disable JavaScript redirects (or ideally, display a prompt)?

The only other way I can think of doing it is to write my own extension that messes around with `window.onbeforeunload` and `window.unload`, but ideally I'd like to use an existing addon.

Comment: Can you give an example? It may be possible with a GM script.

Comment: You can block redirects by setting up an observer on http-modify-request and test if its a redirect and if it is then cancel the rquest. See here for code if you need help modifying that work let us know we can post it down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483651/firefox-addon-monitoring-network/27492685#27492685

Comment: @erosman What do you mean an example?

Comment: How is the redirect implemented? The whole page? elements on the page? Does the JS change the location? Does it insert a meta refresh? What is the JS code that causes the redirect? Is it loaded from external source? Is it part of the page JS?

Comment: @Jez Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @erosman apparently, this method should work for any implementation, and missing some implementation should be handled as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
var {utils: Cu, classes: Cc, instances: Ci, results: Cr} = Components
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var myobserve = function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
    var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);


    if (httpChannel.loadFlags & Ci.nsIHttpChannel.LOAD_REPLACE) {
            //its a redirect, lets block it
            httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);
    }
}
```

I use the presence of flags to test for redirect. Here are some notes i took on flags awhile back, im not totally sure of how accurate these notes are:

> - if has LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI it usually also has LOAD_INITIAL_DOCUMENT_URI if its top window, but on view source we just see LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI. If frame we just see LOAD_DOCUMENT_URI. js css files etc (i think just some imgs fire http modify, not sure, maybe all but not if cached) come in with LOAD_CLASSIFY_URI or no flags (0)
> - note however, that if there is a redirect, you will get the LOAD_DOC_URI and the LOAD_INIT_DOC_URI on initial and then on consequent redirects until final redirect. All redirects have LOAD_REPLACE flag tho
> - note: i think all imgs throw http-on-modify but cahced images dont. images can also have LOAD_REPLACE flag

Of course to start observing:

```
Services.obs.addObserver(myobserve, 'http-on-modify-request', false);
```

and to stop:

```
Services.obs.removeObserver(myobserve, 'http-on-modify-request', false);
```

Comment: How would I implement this as an end-user? I would like to prevent JavaScript from being allowed to redirect the page, or at least not without being allowed.

Comment: @WackGet this is for firefox extensions, you will have to download an extension that does this. There are many out there probably.

Comment: @Noitidart any examples?

Comment: @LogicDaemon there should be on github I'm out of the loop on this stuff for awhile now. :(