# Monitoring Firefox XHR with nsIObserverService

Tags: ajax, firefox, xmlhttprequest, firefox-addon, observers

I am attempting to monitor/intercept all http traffic and push a record of everything to a log.  This works fine for accessing the initial page load, but it doesn't observe anything else (xhr, css, images, etc.).

I have tried the listener method as suggested @ http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/, but this also does not give me the xhr (just the full html reply from the server, not any ajax or other requests).

Here is my observer code:

```
var httpLogger = {
    http_methods_list: [
        'http-on-examine-response',
        'http-on-examine-cached-response',
        'http-on-examine-merged-response'
    ],

    is_enabled: false,
    check_url_list: [ "*" ],
    log: {},

    enable: function() {
        if (! this.is_enabled) {
            this.is_enabled = true;

            var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
            for (var i=0; i < this.http_methods_list.length; ++i) {
                observerService.addObserver( this, this.http_methods_list[i], false );
            }
        }
    },

    disable: function() {
        if (this.is_enabled) {
            this.is_enabled = false;

            var observerService = fxdriver.moz.getService("@mozilla.org/observer-service;1", "nsIObserverService");
            for (var i=0; i < this.http_methods_list.length; ++i) {
                observerService.removeObserver( this, this.http_methods_list[i], false );
            }
        }
    },

    observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
        try {
            if (this.http_methods_list.indexOf(topic) != -1) {
                subject = subject.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);

                if (subject.URI) {
                    url = subject.URI.spec;
                } else if (subject.originalURI) {
                    url = subject.originalURI.spec;
                } else {
                    this._pushToLog( "debug", {event: "no_URI"} );
                    return;
                }

                if (this._urlIsKosher(subject.URI.spec)) {
                    dom_window = this._getDomWindow(subject);

                    event_log = {
                        request: this._getRequestFromSubject(subject),
                        response: this._getResponseFromSubject(subject),
                        responseStatus: subject.responseStatus,
                        responseStatusText: subject.responseStatusText,
                        requestSucceeded: subject.requestSucceeded,
                        requestMethod: subject.requestMethod,
                        status: subject.status,
                        name: subject.name
                    };

                    if (dom_window) {
                        window_handle = this._getWindowHandle(dom_window);
                        if (window_handle) {
                            this._pushToLog( window_handle, event_log );
                        } else {
                            event_log.event = "no_handle";
                            this._pushToLog( "debug", event_log );
                        }
                    } else {
                        event_log.event = "no_window";
                        this._pushToLog( "debug", event_log );
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            this._pushToLog( "debug", {error: err.message} );
        }
    },

    /* other helper functions like this._pushToLog(), this._urlIsKosher(), etc. */

}
```

For example, if I browse to https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/, my logger will record the following:

```
{
    request: {
        Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        Accept-Encoding: 'gzip, deflate',
        Accept-Language: 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Host: 'developer.yahoo.com',
        User-Agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0'
    },
    response: {
        Age: '3',
        Cache-Control: 'private, no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
        Content-Encoding: 'gzip',
        Content-Type: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        Date: 'Fri, 15 May 2015 16:25:28 GMT',
        P3P: 'policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAODSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"',
        Server: 'ATS',
        Set-Cookie: 'B=e2jdjjpalc7fo&b=3&s=ei; expires=Mon, 15-May-2017 16:25:29 GMT; path=/; domain=.yahoo.com',
        Transfer-Encoding: 'chunked',
        Vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
        Via: 'http/1.1 r36.ycpi.bf1.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])',
        X-Frame-Options: 'SAMEORIGIN'
    },
    responseStatus: 200,
    responseStatusText: 'OK',
    requestSucceeded: true,
    requestMethod: 'GET',
    status: 0,
    name: 'https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/'
}
```

But when I click the "Test" button on the yahoo-yql page (which you can see in firebug does an xhr), my logger does not record anything ("debug" or otherwise).

Any advice would be super helpful -- I am rather stuck on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, as I look at my code, I realize that I am not catching any errors in the observe()'s initial if-conditional, and it is in fact throwing "subject.URI is undefined"... so I have to figure out how to get the URI for those

Comment: I have updated the post with the fix in case it is helpful to anyone else

Answer (score 0):

Watch `http-on-modify-request` you'll catch everything

[Firefox addon - monitoring network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483651/firefox-addon-monitoring-network/27492685#27492685)