# Firefox SDK: Get type of observed http request

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I need to intercept HTTP request done by Firefox to set an additional header to the request (like described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers) - but I only want to do this if a Javascript resource is requested (or, equivalent, the request got triggered by an `<script>`tag).

In case of Javascript this sadly cannot be done via looking at the set "accept-encoding" header because this is set to "*/*".

I already analyzed the objects I get handed over when a request is done - but I cannot find the needed information in there.

Does anybody know how one can detect this?

Comment: This topic has a bunch of linked stuff that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483651/firefox-addon-monitoring-network/27492685#27492685 to identify if script etc you will likely be testing `mimeType`