# How to make a addon which will automaticly load missing image after some interval

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want a firefox add-ons , which will automaticly load the missing image after a given interval. and it will stop after the image load. please anyone help me on this .

thanks in advance.

Comment: hi Ashikur and welcome to SO. Are you trying to reload some img that is broken? What are you believing that the second time the image will be downloaded? Furthermore, have you try some code or example? The question is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

Brainstorming an idea - may not be the best approach:

- Add a mutation observer to each document, walk the tree of that node, if anything in there is an image, attach event listener for onerror, and onerror trigger then you know it failed.
- Another way is to use http observer, as you detect its an image (see this topic on how to detect image from http - [Firefox addon - monitoring network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483651/firefox-addon-monitoring-network/27492685#27492685) ) then do some stuff, maybe watch that nsIRequest, and replace it with your own, but keep that original in hand. If the origianl doesnt complete or completes with error code, then try to send the replacement to whatever you want. Sounds cool to me :P just brainstorming - this technique would get the images loaded in css and other places (the first one only gets `<img>`s)